# Spring - How can I adapt SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor to log the data more formally than standard outout to log file

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am trying to perform formal auditing of my Spring web services requests/responses.

I have this in place in my Spring configuration:

```
<ws:interceptors>   
   <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
</ws:interceptors>
```

This is fine, and logs the requests and responses to my JBoss log file. What I want though, is to be able to adapt this and log these requests/responses a little cleaner and how can I get hold of of the data, so I can write to an audit record in the DB.

How can I adapt this above so I can map to one of my beans or similar and get hold of of the data in the requests and responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to create a subclass of `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` and override 
`logMessage(String)` to do what you want. Example:

```
<ws:interceptors>   
   <bean class="org.mypackage.SysErrLoggingInterceptor"/>
</ws:interceptors>


package org.mypackage;

public class SysErrLoggingInterceptor extends SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor {
    @Override
        protected void logMessage(String message) {
        System.err.println(message); 
        /* Example, here you could be logging to DB or whatever you want */
    }

}
```

Comment: Im not the best at Spring configuration. How would I go about doing this? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Excellent answer thank you @artbristol. This has worked great for me.