# Getting XML from Spring Web Service Request

Tags: java, spring, web-services

We need to log all incoming SOAP requests, preferably by persisting to a DB as we have identifying properties that we'd like to associate with it. Is there any way of getting the raw XML data in Spring?

Comment: I found nothing to try - Spring automatically deserializes the objects to match your web service definition before calling your method. I'd imagine there's an interceptor I could add but I can't find where.

Spring provides for logging of web service requests, but I can't associate identifying information in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the source for `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` and/or `PayloadLoggingInterceptor`. You can probably modify this to include what you want.

Another solution could be to put a servlet `Filter` in front of everything that puts the identifying properties into the MDC (assuming you are using SLF4J and/or Log4j/Logback) that way you could configure a jdbc backed Appender which logs to the database.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This pointed me on to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197918/spring-how-can-i-adapt-soapenvelopelogginginterceptor-to-log-the-data-more-for which is pretty much exactly what I'm after.