# how to capture the SOAP packet using Spring-ws 2.0

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I need to capture the complete soap request packet and save it into database.I did try with SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor but no luck...

Myinterceptor

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(some.class);

@Override
    protected void logMessage(String message) {
    System.err.println(message);
    System.out.println("Calling Interceptor");
    logger.debug(message);
    /* Example, here you could be logging to DB or whatever you want */
}
```

}

myendpoint code looks like this

```
  public @ResponsePayload SaveClientResponse saveClientRequest(@RequestPayload GetClientServiceRequest request,MessageContext ctx){
```

}
how can i get the SOAP request packet in endpoint?

My spring Configure is

`enter code here`

Comment: I exactly followed the same steps from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197918/spring-how-can-i-adapt-soapenvelopelogginginterceptor-to-log-the-data-more-for

Comment: Do i need to call the interceptor class from my endpoint?